# How to resize multiple images side by side to to fit the current screen size?

Tags: html, css, image, autoresize

I have a div with 5 rows and with multiple images in it. The Html looks something like this:

```
<div id="row3" class="row">
        <div id="im15" class="column">
            <img src="img/img15.jpg" alt="movie">
        </div>

        <div id="im16" class="column">
            <img src="img/img16.jpg" alt="movie">
        </div>

        <div id="im17" class="column">
            <img src="img/img17.jpg" alt="movie">
        </div>

        <div id="im18" class="column">
            <img src="img/img18.jpg" alt="movie">
        </div>

        <div id="im19" class="column">
            <img src="img/img19.jpg" alt="movie">
        </div>

        <div id="im20" class="column">
            <img src="img/img20.jpg" alt="movie">
        </div>

        <div id="im21" class="column">
            <img src="img/img21.jpg" alt="movie">
        </div>
    </div>
```

I have them side by side and my css looks like this:

```
html, body {
    background-color: #222222;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.column {
    float: left;
}

.column img {
    width:  200px;
    height: 300px;
    padding: 1px;
}

.images {
    opacity: 0.4;
}

.row {
    clear: both;
    display: table;
}
```

It works and displays all images properly stacked with no left space in my screen size laptops, but for bigger screens this fails.

I am not able to understand how can I resize these many images to fit and leave no space for any screen size.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: You can easily do it by using CSS flexbox.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use grid system.

`grid-template-columns` defines how many columns you want to divide, in the flowing example I divide 3 columns with the value `1fr 1fr 1fr`.

`grid-gap` defines the gaps between each grids.

More information about css grid system, you can refer to this Youtube video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jV8B24rSN5o&t=1325s&frags=pl%2Cwn

It's very useful when doing some layouts with CSS.

```css
 .container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-gap: 1em;
  }

  .box {
    border: 1px solid teal;
  }

  .box img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="box">
      <img src="" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <img src="" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <img src="" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <img src="" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <img src="" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <img src="" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <img src="" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Note : This is code for 3 images side by side horizontally

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  padding: 5px;
}

.row::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}
```